# Запланировать задачу на два дня недели

Tags: cmd

Есть задача для работы с командной строкой, а точнее, с командой schtasks:
*создать задание, которое будет запускать каждый второй и четвертый четверг нечетного месяца калькулятор*

Есть вариант, но необходимо выполнить одной командой, используя логическую "и" (так и не разобрался как ее использовать) сделал так:

```
schtasks /create /tn "Calc" /tr calc.exe /sc monthly /mo SECOND /d THU /m jan,mar,may,jul,sep,nov

schtasks /create /tn "Calc1" /tr calc.exe /sc monthly /mo FOURTH /d THU /m jan,mar,may,jul,sep,nov
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь:)

Comment: А что, /MO не принимает список? только одиночное значение? проверьте... И да - для ежемесячного расписания нельзя указывать день недели, только номер дня месяца.

Comment: *необходимо выполнить одной командой, используя логическую "и" (так и не разобрался как ее использовать)* Если имеется в виду объединение команд, то речь идёт о `команда_1 && команда_2`. Команда_2 будет выполнена, если Команда_1 при выполнении вернула нулевой код ошибки.

Comment: @Akina , список не принимает, а судя по документации к данной команде, применять дни недели все же можно.

Comment: Все же разобрался с этим логическим И, не знаю почему(скорее всего косяк во мне), но при попытках ранее вылетала ошибка : schtasks /create /tn "Calc" /tr calc.exe /sc monthly /mo SECOND /d THU /m jan,mar,may,jul,sep,nov && schtasks /create /tn "Calc1" /tr calc.exe /sc monthly /mo FOURTH /d THU /m jan,mar,may,jul,sep,nov